# Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding on Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, mbstring

Is there anybody who can give me a clue?

I'm using php on ubuntu. What bothers me is the error Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() although I've installed mbstring and gd packages and enabled them too. I've also restarted apache2 many times.

```
[Tue Jan 03 14:33:29.036891 2023] [php:error] [pid 2005821] [client 192.168.11.12:34446] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in /var/www/html/...
```

Below is the info

```
$ cat /etc/issue Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS \n \l 
root@***:/usr/lib/php# find . | grep mbstring 
./20220829/mbstring.so 
root@***:/usr/lib/php# php -m | grep mbstring 
mbstring 
root@***:/usr/lib/php# php -m | grep gd 
gd 
root@***:/usr/lib/php# php -v 
PHP 8.2.0 (cli) (built: Dec 10 2022 10:53:01) (NTS) Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.2.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v8.2.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I've also restarted apache2 many times.

Comment: ```sudo apt install php-mbstring```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it didn't work saying "php-mbstring is already the newest version".

Comment: then you *probably* have multiple versions of php installed. what do you get from ```dpkg --get-selections | grep -i php | nc termbin.com 9999``` ?

Comment: I've got "https://termbin.com/wp79".

Comment: oh you actually have 3x different versions of php installed. try ```sudo apt install php-mbstring php8.0-mbstring php8.1-mbstring php8.2-mbstring```

Comment: Command-line and web server do not normally use the same PHP binaries, nor do they necessarily have the same settings. I suggest you do your checks through HTTP (e.g., invoking `phpinfo()`).

Comment: Verify that contents of `/etc/php` look correct. In my case, there's a `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d` that has symlinks to `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available` including fone for php-md and mb-string.